# serverless - AWS Lambda scala example

Tags: scala, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy with serverless a scala project on AWS lambda.
I have followed the tutorial and used [this template](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/tree/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-scala-sbt) where I have only replace the default region with `eu-central-1a` which is where I am based.

I get the error

> ServerlessError: Inaccessible host:
>   `cloudformation.eu-central-1a.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be
>   available in the`eu-central-1a' region.

I could not see any hint of cloudformation not being available in our target region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `eu-central-1a` doesn't represent a region, it represents an availability zone within a region. You should be using the string `eu-central-1` to refer to the region.